# Aurelia-Kendo grid - how get data by button click

Tags: kendo-grid, aurelia

I try to get data for grid by button click.
This is my grid and button:

```
<ak-grid k-data-source.bind="datasource" view-model.ref="gridVM">
        <ak-col k-title="Public Id" k-field="publicId"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="Payment Type" k-field="paymentType"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="Initiated" k-field="initiated"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="Completed" k-field="completed"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="Result" k-field="result"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="State" k-field="state"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="Total" k-field="total"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="User Reference" k-field="userReference"></ak-col>
    </ak-grid>

    <br />
    <button ak-button="k-icon: ungroup; k-widget.bind: button" k-on-click.delegate="GetTransaction()">Get Transactions</button>
```

This is viewmodel file (ts)

```
export class Test{
    gridVM;
    datasource;

    GetTransaction() {
        this.datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "api/getTransaction"
                },
                parameterMap(data, operation) {
                    if (data.models) {
                        return JSON.stringify({ products: data.models });
                    } else if (operation === "read") {
                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                total: "total",
                aggregates: "aggregates"
            },

            pageSize: 5
        })
        this.gridVM.recreate();
    }
}
```

I get data by button click, but only after second click. It seems to me, I get data from previous request. If I change *pazeSize*, I can see another count of records only after second click.

I have checked my network (for debug) and I don't see request *getTransaction* after first click, only after second.

How I can fixed it and to get the correct data after first button click?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are recreating your datasource every time you click your button. The point of a datasource is that you create it once and call the provided methods on your datasource to refresh it.
Also, try to use the recreate() functionality sparsely, you don't need to recreate your entire grid when fetching data, that would defeat the purpose of databinding.

```
<ak-grid k-data-source.bind="datasource" view-model.ref="gridVM">
        <ak-col k-title="Public Id" k-field="publicId"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="Payment Type" k-field="paymentType"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="Initiated" k-field="initiated"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="Completed" k-field="completed"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="Result" k-field="result"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="State" k-field="state"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="Total" k-field="total"></ak-col>
        <ak-col k-title="User Reference" k-field="userReference"></ak-col>
    </ak-grid>

    <br />
    <button ak-button="k-icon: ungroup; k-widget.bind: button" k-on-click.delegate="datasource.fetch()">Get Transactions</button>
```

As you see, you don't even need to make a VM method if all you want to do is fetch some data, just call the fetch() method on your datasource

```
export class Test{
    gridVM;
    datasource;

    constructor() {
        this.datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "api/getTransaction"
                },
                parameterMap(data, operation) {
                    if (data.models) {
                        return JSON.stringify({ products: data.models });
                    } else if (operation === "read") {
                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                total: "total",
                aggregates: "aggregates"
            },

            pageSize: 5
        });
    }
}
```

and move the datasource declaration to your constructor.

Comment: In this case I get data in grid right after page load, but I would like to get it **only** after button click.

Comment: Try setting k-auto-bind.bind="false" on your grid wrapper.
see: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-autoBind

Comment: Sorry very much, perhaps it was my mistake - I didn't describe the full task. The button has been needed not for once-only using. I use filter for data request, and, accordingly, I should have the possibility for multiple buttonk clicking. In constructor case, I get empty values for all filtering fields. I also have changed fetch on read - yes, now I see reaction on succeeding button click (I can see request in Network), but value of filtering fields - empty.

Comment: Under filtering fields I didn't mean grid filtering. These are separate fields - kendo-multiselect & kendo-datetimepicker.

Comment: Then you should read your filter values in your parametermap and append them to your request there. the datasource.fetch() will trigger the parameterMap() function of your datasource